# Finding length of diagonal in compound shape, cuboid and rectangle based pyramid

Tags: angle, solid-geometry

[image]

How to find the length of diagonal and the angle?
Thank you.

Comment: `EFGHI is a rectangular-based pyramid` Is that supposed to mean a [*right pyramid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)#Right_pyramids_with_an_irregular_base)?

Comment: @dxiv yes it is right pyramid

Comment: Then edit the question and state so. "*Rectangular-based pyramid*" is confusing, and most readers would parse it as a pyramid having a rectangular base, which is entirely different.